# How to send Data form view to controller through URL in codeigniter and how i get data in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

How to send Data form view to controller through URL in codeigniter and how I get data in controller?

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-3-text"> <div class="classWithPad"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); echo 'assets/img/'; echo $title[$i]->image; ?>"/> <?php $id = $title[$i]->category_id; ?>
             <div class="title_banner"><a href="<?php echo site_url('Welcome/category','' ) ?>" class="mhover"><?php echo $title[$i]->category_name; ?></a></div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

send like this

Comment: You need to sent data via get method in url and need to use [Input Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) in controller to get the data from URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [$_GET[]](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) method of php:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>your_Controller/your_function?id=1">My Data</a>
```

This will redirect to your `controller` where you had your `function` and within your_function you have to use `$_GET['id']` as

```
function your_function() {
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
}
```

Comment: BUT the ID value genarated by a for loop,  can i assign variable to ID?

Comment: can i have your mail this is mine mruwanc@gmail.com

Comment: i have send you a mail dr